# How to save R object to the disk when permission is denied?

Tags: r, save, rdata

I have computed an R object which takes a lot of time. But while saving it to a file using `write.csv`, I am getting an error as

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'file_name.csv': Permission denied
```

I also tried saving this object to `.rda` file, as well as saving the entire workspace-image to `.RData` file but still getting `permission denied` error. Is there anyway to save this object somehow to the disk instead of running R with root access and re-computing the whole thing again?
............................................................................................................

**Update :**

I am working on `Ubuntu 12.04`.
I tried saving the R object with following methods:

```
1. write.csv(some_dataframe, "file_name.csv")
2. save(some_dataframe, file = "file_name.rda")
3. save.image("~/folder_name/file_name.RData")
```

............................................................................................................

**Answer :**

I created a file with the same name (say `file_name.csv`) using `touch` command. I changed it's access permissions using `chown` command, to own it by me (not a root user). Then I used `write.table` command with `append=TRUE` option to write the dataframe to newly created file, and it worked as expected.

Comment: Do you have enough disk space?

Comment: I guess so. I just tried saving a small sample data-frame (with 2 columns and 4 rows) to a `.csv` file but still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you check? Also, what is the output of `getwd()`? Are you working in the directory you think your are working in?

Comment: Yes I checked. Also I confirmed that I am working in the same directory.

Comment: Okay. I got it. The way I did it was as : I first created an empty file with the same name (using `touch`) and then changed the access permissions for that file (using `chown`). Then I used `write.table` command with `append=TRUE` to write dataframe to that file. It worked as expected. Thanks for your help, Pascal.